# Material UI Paper automatically expand size when i insert an element with negative margin

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

What I want to do is putting a sort of "container" on top of a `Paper` component, but the container should overflow the top of the `Paper`.

[image: This is what I expect:]

I attempted to do this by setting negative `marginTop` for container so it would overflow:

```js
const useStyle = makeStyle({
   container:{marginTop:"-20px"}
});

const classes = useStyle();
return <Paper elevation={1}>
   //the 'container' i chose here is Button component
   <Button className={classes.container}>login</Button> 
   // and some other stuff we don't need to care.
</Paper>
```

It worked ok, but the container is not supposed to be clickable, so it shouldn't be a Button.

And for components other than `Button` ( i tried with `Container`,`Grid`,`Paper`,`Card`), the `Paper` will automatically resize the paper so it could keep the element inside, which is maybe a bug in Material.

Is there anyway, within the scope of Material ,to make this overflow possible? Any help would be appreciated.